# Different ways to say even

Tags: grammar, particle-も, particle-でも

I wanted to say:

> I don't use Skype. I'm so old fashioned that I don't **even** have a mobile (cell) phone.

This is what I went for:

> Skypeを使いません。携帯**も**ないほどなかなか懐古的なのです。

Please correct me if any this is wrong, but the part I was most worried about was **even**. What would be the difference if I had written

> 携帯**でも**ない ...

or

> 携帯**だって**ない ...

How should I decide which is correct or most appropriate?

**Edit**:
Yuuichi Tam brings さえ to the mix as well.

Comment: btw 懐古的 chiefly means "nostalgic" or "good old day-ism". If you're saying you're old fashioned in this way, you can use 昔の人間, 頭が古い and such.

Comment: It should be "Skype は " instead of "Skypeを".

Answer (score 2):

I suggest 携帯さえ持ってないほど. Another option is 携帯すら持ってないほど.

And 携帯でもないほど doesn't make sense but 携帯もないほど and 携帯だってないほど make sense.