# unamed subject in this conversation and use of ~のに... in this sentence

Tags: parsing, reading-comprehension

gossip among unnamed students while being made to run laps, about a time when the ゴリ男 gym teacher got really angry at something.Reader does not anything about what had happened.

> 「これって、この間気持ち悪がったのを怒って仕返ししてるんじゃない？」
>
> 「あ～、あのバレーの時の？」
>
> 「そうそう。ゴリ男から渡されたバレーボールに毛が付いてて気持ち悪がった時のことよ」
>
> 「そういえば凄い怒ってたもんね。もう顔真っ赤にしてさ」
>
> 「あいつの触ったボールも嫌だっていうのに毛だもんね。しかもあれ、縮れてて陰毛みたいだったし」

this(running laps) is revenge, (ゴリ男) is mad at XX for showing signs of being disgusted.

that volleyball time?

yea, that time when the ball that XX got from ゴリ男 had hair attached to it,  XX was disgusted.

Speaking of that, (ゴリ男) was incredibly mad wasn't he,  his face was already bright red.

the ball あいつ(XX?) touched *was pretty unpleasant* のに毛だもんね. Cuz the hair looked like pubes.

- How is ~のに毛だもんね used here?
- is the も in ボールも... the 詠嘆の「モ」?
- is the person (unnamed XX) described as showing 間気持ち悪がる the same person as あいつ in the last sentence?

I found this conversation quite hard to follow.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> あいつの触ったボールも嫌だっていうのに毛だもんね。
>   A ball he (=ゴリ男) touched is already disgusting, but, you know, (this time) it's (ゴリ男's) hair!

あいつ refers to ゴリ男, not the unnamed students. も is "even" (or we can use "already" in this context). のに is like "but". もん is a sentence-end particle used to convince someone or to seek for agreement, like "you know".

Related:

- [What does あいつ and こいつ imply in various situations/contexts?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60737/5010)
- [Meaning of も vs でも for "even"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55740/5010)
- [Different ways to say even](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36173/5010)
- [Ending sentence with ～だもの or ～ですもの](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2240/5010)
- [Etymology of もん・もの](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11703/5010)

Comment: i like to confirm, it explicit that the person(s) that is 間気持ち悪がる is a separate third party, or is the doier this group of gossipers as a whole?

Comment: @charu Since these people actually saw and remember Gorio becoming mad, I tend to think these are the people who made him angry. But it could be a third person. By the way, that 間 is part of [この間](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%93%E3%81%AE%E9%96%93).

Comment: copied an extra character woops. In that case, i think i might have missed something with がる.  I thought is was used for what the speaker thinks someone else is feeling, Why is appropriate to use for one's own feelings here?

Comment: @charu https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3105/5010  You can think of ～がる as "to show signs of ～".